# Usage of ngdocs with controller properties in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc, jsdoc3, grunt-ngdocs

I am just starting to get to grip using grunt-ngdocs for my angular application and so far so good.

But I would now like to document some properties of another documented prperty in one of my controllers.

Consider the following code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  /**
   * @ngdoc controller
   * @name app.mymodule.controller:MyController
   * @description
   * A Controller
   */
  angular
      .module('app.mymodule')
      .controller('MyController', Controller);

  Controller.$inject = ['someService', 'otherService', '$state'];

  function Controller(someService, otherService, $state) {
    /**
     * @ngdoc property
     * @name vm
     * @propertyOf app.mymodule.controller:MyController
     * @description
     * A named variable for the `this` keyword representing the ViewModel
     */
        var vm = this,
      searchText;
    vm.customerService = customerService;
    vm.fetchCollection = fetchCollection;
    vm.deleteCustomer = deleteCustomer;

    initialise();

    function initialise() {
      //logic

    }
    /**
     * @ngdoc
     * @name fetchCollection
     * @methodOf app.mymodule.controller:MyController
     *
     * @description
     * Function to retrieve records from the backend service
     * @example
     * vm.fetchCollection(page, perPage);
     * @param {int} page The number of the page of data to be retrieved
     * @param {int} perPage The number of items per page to be retrieved
     * @returns {object} The response object returned from a httpPromise
     */
    function fetchCollection(page, perPage){
      //logic
    }

    function deleteCustomer(model) {
      //logic
  }
})();
```

As you can see, I have some properties hanging off the vm variable which are typically references to functions defined in the controller.

Using the ngdocs\jsdocs documentation syntax above I can get the vm property to output in my documentation folder, but I am unsure how to document the properties of the vm object itself.

Is there a sensible or recommended way to do this? I did wonder about not documenting vm altogether and just document each of the vm.xxx separately, but I'm not so sure about this!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear in the [documentation](https://github.com/idanush/ngdocs/wiki/API-Docs-Syntax), but you have to use the hash in the name.

Try this.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc property
 * @name app.mymodule.controller:MyController#vm
 * @propertyOf app.mymodule.controller:MyController
 * @description
 * A named variable for the `this` keyword representing the ViewModel
 */
```